How to implement login and registration module in node and react with passportjs
I want to know like there is a three pages login registration and home now I want like before signup or sign in user should not be able to access home page now how to implement that like normally and also like how to go from one page to another page because now when click in frontend (Login.jsx) login button now in server my details got checked and then how do I go to Home.jsx.
Is this logic is correct:
const App = () => {
    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            <Router>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/login" element={<PrivateRoute component={Login} redirectTo="/home" />} />
                    <Route path="/register" element={<PrivateRoute component={Register} redirectTo="/home" />} />
                    <Route path="/home" element={<ProtectedRoute component={Home} redirectTo="/login" />} />
                    <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/login" />} />
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        </AuthProvider>
    );
};

